# Что лучше require или import в node.js?

Tags: node.js

```
не знаю что использовать require или import в node.js?
```

Answer (score -2):

Import не будет работать в nodejs искоропки. Только с помощью доп пакетов. Их много разных. Советую юзать require, как нативное средство ноды.

Comment: это ошибочное утверждение так как https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/esm.html